# Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

Tags: eclipse, osgi, classnotfoundexception, eclipse-pde

I'm Using Eclipse SDK to develop my bundles. But whenever I want to export (File -> Export -> Plug-in Development -> "Deployable plug-ins and fragment") the Bundle I receive the following error screen. is there any solution or particular reason?

[image: Problem Occurred]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to check the "Use class files compiled in the workspace" checkbox in options tab!

[image].

Answer (score 0):

It means that you're missing a JAR from your CLASSPATH.

You can use FindJar to help you find it:

http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter

Comment: Where should the JAR file be? I've checked the .classpath file and it is not used there! Could you please explain more?